# how to add a foreign key in mysql (connector with python)

Tags: python, mysql, database, mysql-connector-python

i have this part of a python  script to create tables into a mysql db

```
#Product
TABLES['product'] = (
"CREATE TABLE product"
 "(prod_id smallint,"
  "name varchar(255),"
  "price int,"
  "constraint pk_prod_id primary key (prod_id)"
 ");")

#Sales
TABLES['sales'] = (
"CREATE TABLE sales"
 "(sales_id smallint,"
  "name varchar(255),"
  "quantity int,"
  "buy_id smallint,"
  "date DATE,"  
  "constraint pk_sales_id primary key (sales_id,name)"
 ");")
#Purchase
TABLES['purchase'] = (
"CREATE TABLE purchase"
 "(purchase_id smallint,"
  "name varchar(255),"
  "quantity int,"
  "sup_id smallint,"
  "date DATE,"  
  "constraint pk_purchase_id primary key (purchase_id,name)"
  ");")

# Adding foreign key
query =  'ALTER TABLE sales ADD foreign key(buy_id) references buyers(buy_id)'
cursor.execute(query)
query = 'ALTER TABLE purchase ADD foreign key(sup_id) references suppliers(sup_id)'
cursor.execute(query)
```

Until here it works ok,  but here is the main problem.

```
query = 'ALTER TABLE sales ADD foreign key(name) references product(name)'
cursor.execute(query)
query = 'ALTER TABLE purchase ADD foreign key(name) references product (name)'
cursor.execute(query)
```

the error code is 1215, so can't add foreign keys

It works if i do this

```
query = ('ALTER TABLE sales ADD foreign key(prod_id) references product(prod_id)')
cursor.execute(query)
query = ('ALTER TABLE purchase ADD foreign key(prod_id) references product(prod_id)')
cursor.execute(query)
```

but i prefer to work with name and not with prod_id because it's a mess.

how can i solve this issues ? i tried with int type, but i don't like this solution, moreover i have to rewrite a lot of query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the table product like this with KEY (name)

```
#Product
TABLES['product'] = (
"CREATE TABLE product"
 "(prod_id smallint,"
  "name varchar(255),"
  "price int,"
  "constraint pk_prod_id primary key (prod_id),"
  "KEY (name)"
 ");")
```

And you can without probems add a foreign key to product name

Comment: it works, but i have to rewrite all the query, for istance : without adding the previous foreign key i could use this :